# Is it possible to register an appointment in several Outlook accounts since vb?

Tags: vba, vb.net, outlook, appointment

I am using the following code but I only registered the appointment in the main mail account, I would like to know it is possible to register the direct appointment in another Outlook account:

```
.Recipients.Add("Roger Harui")
            Dim sentTo As Outlook.Recipients = .Recipients
            Dim sentInvite As Outlook.Recipient
            sentInvite = sentTo.Add("Holly Holt")
            sentInvite.Type = Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired
```

Comment: Do you actually call AppointmentItem.Send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Send` method sends an item using the default account specified for the session.

```
Private Sub CreateMeeting()
  Dim appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem = _
    CType(Application.CreateItem( _
    Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem), Outlook.AppointmentItem)
  appt.Subject = "Customer Review"
  appt.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting
  appt.Location = "36/2021"
  appt.Start = DateTime.Parse("19/04/2017 10:00 AM")
  appt.End = DateTime.Parse("19/04/2017 11:00 AM")
  Dim recipRequired As Outlook.Recipient = _
      appt.Recipients.Add("Ryan Gregg")
  recipRequired.Type = _
      Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired
  Dim recipOptional As Outlook.Recipient = _
      appt.Recipients.Add("Peter Allenspach")
  recipOptional.Type = _
      Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olOptional
  Dim recipConf As Outlook.Recipient = _
      appt.Recipients.Add("Conf Room 36/2021 (14) AV")
  recipConf.Type = _
      Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olResource
  appt.Recipients.ResolveAll()
  appt.Send()
End Sub
```

See [How to: Specify Different Recipient Types for an Appointment Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184622.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for the contribution really helped me a lot